# How can I listen to a whole album on iTunes?

Tags: itunes, music, album

I can not listen to a whole album on iTunes, I have tried "ticking or checking all the songs in my library" and preferences/unchecking the list view check boxes. nothing works. Can anyone help me please?

Comment: Reading the manual of a new device or the help topics related to new software should be the first task of a customer before ranting to the manufacturer.

Comment: Your comment was not very helpful, thank you however for taking the time to write a useless answer. Ive already read the threads and done what it was suggested on them and it has not worked. From a customer and a product manager point of view, changing the functions of a program/ software forcing the customer to study the manual of a product is hardly an improvement. FYI I am  not the only person with this problem.

Comment: I wanted to express that 2/3 of your question was a rant at Apple - which isn't very helpful here at apple.stackexchange. Make a complaint in an Apple Store or write to Apple's customer support. You should have added details like your Apple device, your system and iTunes version to your question instead. I will write an answer which is helpful. And Apple's solution to play whole albums is adequately intuitive.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you are using a Mac with a newer system and the latest iTunes do the following:

1. Go to Album view

   [image]
2. Now move the cursor to an album which will "enable" a play button in the lower right corner. Hit the play button to play all songs of this album:

   [image]
3. If you click once more on the album you will see the content of the album:

   [image]
4. To see the content of another album click on it - this won't interrupt the playback of the first album:

   [image]
5. To play the second album either

   - move the cursor over the second album and click on the then enabled play button
   - move the cursor over the cover of the "expanded" album and click on the then visible bigger blue-on-white play button

   [image]

   - move the cursor over one of the titles of the "expanded" album and click on the then visible small blue play button